# Extract vectors from nested loops in R as vectors

Tags: r, vector, nested-loops

I'm learning to use R and I'm trying to extract cont, p0 and pf variables from nested loop as 3 different vectors from this code.

```
v<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
n<-length(v)
mv<-5
a<-n-(mv-1)
cont<-0
for (num in (a-1):0){
  for (i in 0:num){
    cont<-cont+1
    p0<-v[a-num]
    pf<-v[n-i]
  }
}
```

The expected result should be:

```
> print(cont)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> print (p0)
[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "d"
> print (pf)
[1] "h" "g" "f" "e" "h" "g" "f" "h" "g" "h"
```

Comment: Insofar you are learning R I strongly advice you against nested `for` loops (depending on what you are doing with them you can slow down your code significantly). In R, it is worth it to learn how to use the `apply` function "family" and their parallelized equivalents. For example: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without explicit `for` loop :

```
v <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
n <- length(v)
mv <- 5
a <- n-(mv-1)
cont <- 0

p0 <- rep(v[1:a], a:1)
pf <- v[unlist(sapply((n-a + 1):n, function(x) n:x))]

p0
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "d"
pf
# [1] "h" "g" "f" "e" "h" "g" "f" "h" "g" "h"
```

If you need `cont` you could use `p0` or `pf` with `seq_along`.

```
cont <- seq_along(p0)
cont
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I would keep `cont` as an index variable and store the other variables in vectors.

```
v<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
n<-length(v)
mv<-5
a<-n-(mv-1)
cont = 0
cont_stored = vector();
p0 = vector();
pf = vector();

for (num in (a-1):0){
  for (i in 0:num){
    cont <- cont+1
    cat("cont = ", cont, "\n"); ## useful function for printing stuff out in loops
    cont_stored[cont] = cont;
    p0[cont] = v[a-num]
    pf[cont] = v[n-i]
  }
}
cont_stored
p0
pf
```